# C++: use a subtype of undefined class

Tags: c++, oop

Creating header for new class I avoid including other class definition. Normally it works well, especially when I include this class definition in .cpp files. Things like:

```
class B{
    class A *ptr;
};
```

works pretty well. But when A has a subtype (for example, A::AA), I can't use this subtype in B class definition. How could I do it to avoid including A header in B header? (and include it in B.cpp file instead).

Comment: Basically, you can't. You can only declare a *nested-class* within a definition of a *class*.

Comment: You can't deal with a class by value unless you have the class defined at that point. Concretely, if `B` wants to have a member variable of type `AA`, not pointer to `AA`, it needs to see the entire definition of `AA` where it's defined. The easiest way to see this is the fact that `B`'s definition must have enough information to tell the compiler how to lay out `B` in memory. You can't know that without knowing the size/alignment of `AA`.